# Chain commands with Control + C interrupt

Tags: bash, command-line, kill, signals

I am trying to execute a program which loops indefinitely, and so must be forcibly interrupted. After executing the program, I want to delete it. I can do it in several steps:

1. `./MyProg`
2. <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
3. `rm MyProg`

but I need to do this often, so I'd like to have steps 1 and 3 on a single line for easy history recall.

I have tried the following, but in each case the <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> interrupt kills the whole line, not just the executing program, and so the file is never deleted:

```
./MyProg && rm MyProg
./MyProg;   rm MyProg
./MyProg || rm MyProg
```

How can I get the interrupt to affect only the running program, and not the whole command line?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `trap` mechanism inside your `MyProg` to clean up after the program is exiting.

```
trap "rm MyProg" EXIT
```

If the MyProg is not a bash script, you can wrap your program in a bash script.